# Win10 VPN never prompts for user/pass

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, credentials

I believe this started after 1903 update.  To connect to VPN I have always clicked on the networking icon in the system tray to bring up list of VPN connections and then I click on the Connect button for the appropriate VPN.  The ones which have a password stored connect fine but the ones that do not have a password stored (I use WiKID for generating dynamic password) just sit there spinning and never prompts.

My settings:

[image: VPN Settings]

My VPN Adapter Security properties:

[image: VPN Adapter Security properties]

I haven't been able to find a report of this issue. I have tried to delete and recreate the VPN connection but still get the same symptom.  I am aware of other ways to launch a VPN connection but am looking for a way to get the built-in method working again to prompt for user/password.

Note going through the Windows Settings VPN page, the connect button DOES bring up prompt as expected:

[image: VPN Settings Connect]
[image: VPN credentials prompt]

Event Viewer message generated when attempting to conenct to VPN through system tray:
[image: DistributedCOM error screenshot]

Comment: Could you post an image of your VPN configuration settings?

Comment: probably easier to delete the VPN virtual adapter (through Network & Sharing Centre) and re-create it...

Comment: @NiallJones - posted a screenshot of setting window though nothing special.  Is there other useful screen?

Comment: @Kinnectus - I have tried to delete and re-create but still get same symptom

Comment: Have you deleted the virtual adapter, definitely?

Comment: @Kinnectus - Yes deleted through Network Connections. Also did remove through VPN Settings window.

Comment: Go to VPN settings > Change adapter options (on the right) > right-click on the VPN adapter and select properties. Could you send a screenshot of the security tab?

Comment: @NiallJones - posted screenshot of VPN Adapter Security properties

Comment: Try setting the encryption setting to "Require Encryption".

Comment: I could be off base here but IPSec uses the concept of a preshared key. Where would a username and password come in to play (it even says optional on the one screenshot)? I think what you are looking for is to enable one of the “authentication” options on the VPN properties page you sent a screenshot of above. If you’re using a username / password as well, you must be logging in to something using EAP, PAP, MS-CHAP, etc.

Comment: @NiallJones - Changed the Data encryption from Optional to Required but still did not bring prompt

Comment: @sonyisda1 - read Appleoddity's comment... you're using L2TP/IPSec....

Comment: @Kinnectus I saw the comment but there is no question about user/pass.  It is required for my type of vpn configuration and have been using it this way for years.  The problem is that the system tray connection method **never** prompts for user/pass (which is required for me) like it **does** through the VPN Settings window.  Nevertheless I did try to enable one/many/all protocol options but still did not enable the prompting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been resolved since the [October 24, 2019—KB4522355 (OS Build 18362.449) update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4522355).

There is a seemingly ambiguous change highlighted:

> Updates an issue that prevents you from connecting to a virtual
>   private network (VPN).